# JavaScript. Создание превью файла при загрузке с помощью FileReader или createObjectURL

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, файлы, fileupload

Задался вопросом о получении превью и начальной информации о файле до его загрузки. Почти все, что я читал об этом, основывается на использовании объекта FileReader() в JavaScript.
Однако для того, чтобы отобразить превью, нужно сначала получить объект файла из input и передать его в FileReader, а FileReader в свою очередь ждет загрузки файла (если я правильно понял, то во временную папку) и поэтому если передать объекту достаточно большой файл, то превью будет создаваться очень долго. Поэтому я нашел решение с использованием URL.createObjectURL в который также передается объект файла и который сразу же дает ссылку на файл в виде "blob:ссылка", при чем можно сразу получить превью видео или изображения любых размеров.
Собственно почему почти всегда используют FileReader, если он не позволяет сделать превью сразу для больших файлов?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Сравнение:

### 1) время выполнения

- `createObjectURL` выполняется синхронно(очень быстро)
- `FileReader.readAsDataURL` асинхронный, требует callback(действительно не такой быстрый)

### 2) использование памяти

- `createObjectURL` возвращает blob url текущего сайта(`blob:http://examle.com/f91de9c4-b515-4615-9895-15089b364b7f`), и сохраняет объект в памяти до тех пор пока не наступит событие unload (т.е. закрытие документа) или пока не будет вызвано `revokeObjectURL`
- `FileReader.readAsDataURL` возвращает `base64` который содержит много символов, и использует больше памяти чем blob url, но удаляется с памяти если не используется(благодаря garbage collector).

### 3) поддержка

- `createObjectURL` от IE 10 и выше и во всех современных браузерах
- `FileReader.readAsDataURL` от IE 10 и выше и во всех современных браузерах

---

**Если надо сделать превью для картинки, то лично я предпочитаю использование blob url's (через `createObjectURL`), это более эффективно и быстрее, но помните что если используете много объектов, то обязательно используйте `revokeObjectURL` (чтобы освободить память). Что касается FileReader, он хорошо подходит если надо получить base64 строку, которую можно передать в api, например, и сохранить при этом саму картинку, такое не сделаешь с blob, но если надо просто сделать превью картинки, то `createObjectURL` эффективней!**.

Для примера, вы можете вызвать URL.revokeObjectURL внутри onload обработчика картинки и после этого объект картинки будет содержать данные картинки, без потерь.

- [Хорошая статья](https://chrisrng.svbtle.com/using-url-createobjecturl)
- [FileReader.readAsDataURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsDataURL)
- [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader)
- [URL.createObjectURL()](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/URL/createObjectURL)

Пример использования:

**FileReader**

```
input.onchange = function (event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0]
  var reader = new FileReader()
  reader.onloadend = function () {
    console.log('RESULT', reader.result)
  }
  reader.readAsDataURL(file)
}
```

**URL.createObjectURL()**

```
input.onchange = function (event) {
  var file = event.target.files[0]
  var url = URL.createObjectURL(file)
  console.log('RESULT', url )
}
```